# Why doesn't strncpy work with a string allocated with malloc?

Tags: c, string, memory-management, malloc

```
char* temp;

temp = (char*) malloc (strlen(window->entry.value)+1);
//strncpy( temp, window->entry.value, sizeof(temp) ); DOESN"T WORK
memcpy (temp, window->entry.value, strlen(window->entry.value) + 1); //WORKS
```

(where window->entry.value is a string.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof(temp)` doesn't do what you think it does. It tells you the size, in bytes, of a pointer to char, which is what `temp` is. Most likely on your system either 4 or 8.

This has nothing to do with the length of any particular string, or the size of any particular buffer returned from `malloc`.

It's pure fluke that you've passed the right length when using `memcpy`, and the wrong length when using `strncpy`. `memcpy` would also not work if passed `sizeof(temp)` as the length, and `strncpy` would work if passed the right length.

Answer (score 0):

Strncpy doesn't care where you get your memory. The fact that you used sizeof(temp) shows that you don't know left from right in C strings, because that only works for statically allocated char[] buffers. The reason that memcpy works and strncpy doesn't is because you actually passed a sensible length parameter to memcpy but totally forgot to make this parameter make any sense to strncpy.